# Change command depending on the tcolorbox it's in

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I have a  command `\kw` which simply formats text in bold, with a certain colour. This is used for keywords, both in normal text, where it defaults to some predefined colour, and in boxes, where I'd like it to assume the colour of the box (or rather its title).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.08,0.61,0.32}
\definecolor{bggreen}{rgb}{0.953,0.98,0.949}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0.24,0.24}
\definecolor{bgred}{rgb}{0.988,0.937,0.937}
% Etc.

% Set the colour of the default for various boxes
\newcommand*{\setaccentcolour}[1]{
    \colorlet{accentcolour}{#1}

    \tcbset{
        accent/.style={
            colback=bg#1,
            colbacktitle=bg#1,
            coltitle=#1,
        }
    }
}
\setaccentcolour{green}

% Sets of colours for manually changing
\tcbset{
    red/.style={
        colback=bgred,
        colbacktitle=bgred,
        coltitle=red,
    },
    % Etc.
}

\newcommand*{\kw}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{accentcolour}{#1}}}

\NewTcbTheorem{definition}{Definition}{accent}{def}

\NewTColorBox{callout}{ O{accent} }{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{callout}[red]
    % I'd like this to use the title colour (even though there's no title here) which is `red'
    This is \kw{coloured} text!
\end{callout}

% This is green, as expected
And some more \kw{coloured} text.

\begin{definition}{Test}{}
    % This is also green
    This is also \kw{coloured}.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

I'm not going to consider using different commands in each box, or explicitly changing the colour as that destroys the semantic meaning of the command.

I tried using the `tcbcoltitle` colour which tcolorbox defines, which worked well, but then I still need a way to tell if the command is called inside a colour box or not. I.e.

```latex
\begin{definition}{Test}{}
    This is \textcolor{tcbcoltitle}{coloured} text!
\end{definition}
```

Gives text which matches the box title colour, but to put this in a command would require knowing when to apply `tcbcoltitle` (when in a box) or when to default to some basic `kwcolour` (when not in a box).

Comment: Welcome! Can you include the`tcbcoltitle` case since that seems to get you part of what you want?

Comment: @Len It would make things a lot easier if you just provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of code snippets ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht sorry, there's a lot of moving parts in a slightly old preamble so I didn't have time to pick it all apart and make a MWE. I've added one now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `\kw` to select a custom color for the text which you can then (re-)define inside the relevant `tcolorbox` using the `code` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myredbox}{
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black
}

\newtcolorbox{mybluebox}{
    colback=blue!5!white,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    code={\colorlet{kwcolor}{red}}
}

\colorlet{kwcolor}{blue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\kw}{ m }{%
    \textcolor{kwcolor}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myredbox}
Foo \kw{bar} baz
\end{myredbox}

\begin{mybluebox}
Foo \kw{bar} baz
\end{mybluebox}

\begin{myredbox}
Foo \kw{bar} baz
\end{myredbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Same approach (and same output) with `\NewTotalTColorBox`es:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\myredbox}{ m }{
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black
}{ #1 }

\NewTotalTColorBox{\mybluebox}{ m }{
    colback=blue!5!white,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    code={\colorlet{kwcolor}{red}}
}{ #1 }

\colorlet{kwcolor}{blue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\kw}{ m }{%
    \textcolor{kwcolor}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\myredbox{Foo \kw{bar} baz}

\mybluebox{Foo \kw{bar} baz}

\myredbox{Foo \kw{bar} baz}

\end{document}
```

---

I stitched together the snippets you added to the recent edit to your question and I hope that this is about right. As far as I can see, you can still use the approach described above here.

The color redefinition via `code` is scoped to the current box. So, if the color is `red` outside the box and you redefine it to be `blue` (or `tcbcoltitle`) inside the box, the defintion of the color will still be `red` if used outside the box later:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{
    accent/.style={
        colback=blue!25,
        colbacktitle=blue!25,
        coltitle=blue,
        code={\colorlet{kwcolour}{tcbcoltitle}}
    },
}

\NewTcbTheorem[
    Crefname={Definition}{Definitions}
]{definition}{Definition}{accent}{def}

\colorlet{kwcolour}{red}

\newcommand*{\kw}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{kwcolour}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Foo \kw{bar} baz

\begin{definition}{Foo}{foo}
Foo \kw{bar} baz
\end{definition}

Foo \kw{bar} baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Also with your MWE, this solution works as expected if you use the `code` option as described above. You just need to set `code={\colorlet{accentcolour}{tcbcoltitle}` after having set `coltitle=red` of course:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.08,0.61,0.32}
\definecolor{bggreen}{rgb}{0.953,0.98,0.949}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0.24,0.24}
\definecolor{bgred}{rgb}{0.988,0.937,0.937}
% Etc.

% Set the colour of the default for various boxes
\newcommand*{\setaccentcolour}[1]{
    \colorlet{accentcolour}{#1}

    \tcbset{
        accent/.style={
            colback=bg#1,
            colbacktitle=bg#1,
            coltitle=#1,
        }
    }
}
\setaccentcolour{green}

% Sets of colours for manually changing
\tcbset{
    red/.style={
        colback=bgred,
        colbacktitle=bgred,
        coltitle=red,
        code={\colorlet{accentcolour}{tcbcoltitle}}
    },
    % Etc.
}

\newcommand*{\kw}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{accentcolour}{#1}}}

\NewTcbTheorem{definition}{Definition}{accent}{def}

\NewTColorBox{callout}{ O{accent} }{#1}

\begin{document}

Some \kw{coloured} text.

\begin{callout}[red]
    % I'd like this to use the title colour (even though there's no title here) which is `red'
    This is \kw{coloured} text!
\end{callout}

% This is green, as expected
And some more \kw{coloured} text.

\begin{definition}{Test}{}
    % This is also green
    This is also \kw{coloured}.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is I can't reset `kwcolor` after, which I need to be able to do.

Comment: @Len Do you even need to this? As you can see in the example above, the new color defintion is scoped inside the `tcolorbox`. Therefore it is automatically reset to `blue` in the third box. Please consider providing an example that shows your use case. It is hard to come up with solution that might help you.

Comment: I've updated my question as others asked. I use `\kw` in normal text as well as in boxes, so it needs to default back to a basic colour in normal text.

Comment: @Len See my edit.

Comment: See my updated question. My problem now is that the `code` option is executed immediately, so it doesn't catch if I pass in a different colour to the box as an argument.

I realise this probably seems very convoluted but there's a lot of different boxes with different uses in addition to the example. 

It seems the easiest way to do this would be for `\kw` to know when its inside a box, and then grab the value of `tcbcoltitle`.

Comment: @Len I don't get your problem honestly. It works as expected if you place the `code` option as described in the other examples. See my edit.

Comment: It seems my issue is that I'm putting the `code` option somewhere else in a `tcbset{}` where I also apply some other options to all layers. Therefore `tcbcoltitle` isn't updated with the new colour that's been passed in. You've put it in the `red` style after the  new colours have been applied. I'd rather not put that line in everywhere but I suppose I could.

Comment: @Len Yes, you should indeed place this line after `tcbcoltitle` has been updated with the new color. Although the color name is the same as before, it is not the same color, as it has been updated. This might require that you place this line several times. You could define another style using `setaccentcolor/.style={code={\colorlet{accentcolour}{tcbcoltitle}}}` and then just call `setaccentcolor` at the places where you need to update the `accentcolor`. This could help to streamline your code.

Comment: Yep that's probably what I'll do. Thanks for all the help.